# Spark Sql JDBC to RDBMS get count of table efficiently

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Consider spark jdbc dataframe to a rdbms table as given below

```
val df = spark.read("jdbc").option("url", url).option("dbtable", "schema.table").option("user", user).option("password",passwor).load()
df.count
```

This count action is not recomended since it will load data into spark layer and take count in the Spark layer instead of pushing down count query to jdbc datasource.  What is the efficient way to get the count in this scenario?

Comment: Point is do you need these rows from that table subsequently?

Answer (score 2):

Typically count will only be used once in your business logic (this is just an assumption), so the recommended way to do it is to use a standard `jdbc connection` and execute and `sql statement` that counts the rows. In this way it will be executed directly in the database and not through spark. Something like this might help you:

```
 val query = s"select count(*) from schema.table"
    val connection = getMySqlConnection(...)
    val rs = connection.createStatement().executeQuery(query)
    rs.next()
    val count = rs.getLong(1)
    connection.close()
    count
```

Comment: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-jdbc.html    What about the query option?

Comment: Thank you dumitru and @thebluephantom. My intention was to see if there is any work around.